# A function f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(n)=0$ for all integers $n$, then $f$ may not always uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I tried to find such example that f is not uniformly continuous. But if I think it by graphically, then this function return to x axis every time at integers with a continuous arc. I don't understand how do it possible to be not uniformly continuous. Please help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need it to get steeper and steeper as you go along, so something like 
$$f(x)=x\sin(\pi x)$$
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For each $n$ draw a triangle with vertices $(n-\frac{2}{n},0) , (n-\frac{1}{n},1), (n,0)$.

Comment: is this for $n>0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It can work both ways: for $n>0$ or for all non-zero integers.

Answer (score 2):

Uniformly continuous means that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is controlled uniformly by $|x-y|$. So to "make" a function non-uniformly continuous, one attempt would be to ensure the following : for every $\epsilon$ small enough and $K$ large enough, ensure that there are a pair of points $x,y$ such that $|x-y| < \epsilon$ but $|f(x) - f(y)| > K$. Then such a function won't be uniformly continuous.

By the mean value theorem (assuming the function is differentiable wherever required) this would happen if the derivative of $f$ can be found to be arbitrarily large in places.

For example, since $f$ is pinned to zero at the integers, it can do what it wants between them as long as it is continuous. The idea is simple : the graph of $f$ should be very "slopy" so that $f$ changes very fast in these parts. Such a  slope is clearly introduced by a graph looking like a steep triangle!

So the idea is to create an $f$ whose graph looks like triangles getting progressively steep, with base resting on the $x$-axis. Try to draw this for yourself!

(Others have provided the details : I provide the reason why this construction works).

Comment: Your explanation is excellent sir. I am pleased with such a mathematical way of presenting uniform continuity.

Comment: @MANISHANKARPANDEY You are welcome! I am pleased to inform you that upon careful browsing you will find people better than me, so you are likely to be even more pleased as you go along. Kindly continue to frequent the site, your happiness will be up multifold.

Comment: @actoh Sure sir

Answer (score 0):

Another example, which is continuous but not uniformly continuous with the above condition is $x^{2}\sin(\pi x)$. One fact that may help you is that if $f$ is an u.c function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then the absolute of $f$ is somehow linear that is there exists $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $|f| \leq $a|x|+b$. This may give you some intuition on looking for functions that are continuous but not u.c.